# Disallow google/other email plus and dot tricks when registering?

Tags: user-registration

A user registered with my WordPress blog as "bob.smith+bc@gmail.com" 
(for example).

I'm fine with that. However, if the user comes back with 
"bob.smith+bc2@gmail.com", I want to stop him for registering again, 
and maybe politely remind him that he's already registered with the 
"same" gmail address.

Is there a plugin that does this?

Same question for things like "bob.smith@gmail.com" and 
"b.ob.smith@gmail.com" (using extra dots in the email address, which 
gmail recognizes as the same address).

I realize people can easily get free no-registration-required email 
addresses, so this won't stop someone from registering multiple times, 
but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `user_register` hook to normalize the email address and either store it in a separate field in the database or just do a query to see if the normalized email address matches. I don't see one that is a `pre-user_register` hook though, so it appears that you would have to delete the user after it was created if the user is already registered.

Here is the link to the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

And here is a stackoverflow question about normalizing gmail addresses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592956/gmail-username-collapsing

And some code to do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586389/how-to-check-for-a-duplicate-email-address-in-php-considering-gmail-user-name